# How to call same job twise in pentaho job with different parameter?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am creating pentaho jobs

- In first set variable box i am passing value sysdate the first dfp job working perfectly.
- In second set variable box i am passing value sysdate+1 ,so sysdate+1 file is picked correctly to process but second dfp job only getting error.

Is this logic is possible in pentaho Jobs?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have numerous example of that kind that works perfectly every night. And I guess the `Set variables` have the appropriate level (valid in parent job).

So the bug is probably in the value you give to the variable in `Set variable 2`. The value `sysdate+1` has the literal value (the string "sysdate+1") not the Date of tomorrow.

You must first compute that value. Which is done in a transformation replacing `Set variable 2`, which would do something like this: [image]

Comment: Thanks for spending time.......But set variable 2 (date) is correctly picking my file and processing .....In job only i am getting error........

Comment: add a "Write to log" step before that second job and type in the value you're passing. Just to be sure you are passing the value you think you are.

Comment: @Nsousa :Thanks..... Like that only i captured my date it printed correctly. it's picking correct file also to start to process but while running same job second time i am getting error....

Comment: Put a `write to log` at the beginning of DFP2, what does it says?
Then start DFP2 from the console giving that exact value as parameter (you can set the parameters in the "run" screen). Does it run?      
No? Then debug DFP2 with that exact value as parameters. When finished just run the parent job with no modif.